# Unity C# issue with Getting a mesh from a child object with a tag

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to swap meshes of a parent object based on tags of its children , after a bool has been activated . I have just learned to use this method with using Foreach in a variable ( I am not sure if it has a specific name).

The problem however is that it does not seem to affect the mesh filter on any of the objects at all , it returns the Debug values fine meaning it has found the objects but never changes them.

if anyone has any suggestions or knows what the issue might be it would be of great help

```
if (NKCell.GetComponent<ModelChangeScript>().HighqualityModel)
{
    Transform[] HQTransforms = this.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>();

    foreach (Transform t in HQTransforms)
    {
        if (t.gameObject.tag == "HighQualityModel")

        {
            HQMesh = t.GetComponent<MeshFilter>();

            gameObject.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh = HQMesh.mesh;

            Debug.Log("Found " + t);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what type is HQMesh ? A MeshFilter ? I just tested your code and it works fine for me. Is the script attached to the parent ?

Comment: Not related to your problem, but Unity recommends you do `t.gameObject.CompareTag("HighQualityModel")` instead of `t.gameObject.tag == "HighQualityModel"`. It compiles to fewer machine code instructions

Comment: HQMesh should be a mesh, not a meshfilter. unsure this will be enough in your case though

Comment: Uri Popov : they are as meshfilters yes and yes they are all attached to parent objects

Comment: Scott Chamberlain : Thank you that is useful to know .

Comment: Mark , I have tried replacing them to just Meshes , however when the bool is activated it makes the objects disappear.